# Having a ngModel inside ngbTabContent issue

Tags: angular

ngModel not working inside ngbTabContent

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpmdsy-oxnpss

if I have a ngmodel inside ngbTabContent ngModel value is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p [(ngModel)]="test"></p>` -> This is **wrong**

You cannot have `[(ngModel)]` in a `<p>` or a `<div>`.It is used to set property in **input fields**

To display `test` property value use simple **interpolation**

> {{test}}

Also you need to pass `test` as input to your child component. Check the demo I shared.

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpmdsy-48wfeg?embed=1&file=app/tabset-basic.html)

Comment: What could be the best way to display the value of test if it had html tags? besides innerHTML?

Comment: Yes... `<p [innerHTML]="test"></p>`